# where is common.min.js located?

Tags: splunk, branding

We are working on a project which involves custom branding. We are using a tool called Splunk. We need to add a label along with Splunk logo. We investigated with firebug and we could see that there is a references to that splunk logo in common.js and common.min.js file. We are using splunk version6.2. We located the common.js file in the below path.

```
(Path :home dir\Splunk\share\splunk\search_mrsparkle\exposed\js\build\bundles\common.js ). When we changed the logo in common.js file, we were able to see the changes, refelected. 

So we tried to searched for the common.min.js file, we were not able to locate that file. 

Can some one throw some light on where this common.min.js file will be located. If we are able to locate it, we will be able to make our branding changes.

From the Firebug, we are able to see that that common.min.js file is located in the http://domainname/static/@245427/js  path. We are not able to locate that file in our server.

Any help on this is appreciated.
```